# Tiles are not well fetched

Tags: react-leaflet

I can't retrieve all the tiles, only few random tiles are loaded from Network tab (even 304) and displayed.

At each render, I can zoom or move across the map there is still missing tiles, I think it's a problem during the tiles calls. I try to reach the tiles fetching code part but it's quite hard to find it ;).

Maybe I missed a configuration step or something like this, but I read it again and same issue.

I precise that all my deps are up-to-date (react, react-dom 16.4.1).

Thanks for you help,

Kannar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is the result of misconfiguration, the common issues are:

1) `Leaflet CSS file` is missing, make sure it is included, for example:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css'>
```

2) map container (`.leaflet-container`) size needs to be explicitly specified, for example:

```
.leaflet-container {
   height: 420px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Here is [demo](https://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/VBWoBO) for your reference.

[And here is a thread](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/108) with similar behavior